# Is there some completion plugin that can display the details of the currently selected item below the completion list?

Tags: completion

When you use a dialog such as with `C-x b`, `C-x C-b` or `C-x k` the columns are usually not long enough, especially with long file names and directories.

Is it possible to have a detail view below the completion list, that will show the currently selected item below the completion list, with labels on the left and the values on the right.

A file selection dialog may look like this

[image]

So if I was on the row with `another filename` below the list I would have something like this

[image]

Is there some plugin for something like this?

Not only that when you navigate a list, shouldn't it be possible to scroll through the truncated columns to see more detail?

This problem is ruining the emacs experience for me. For instance it makes it hard to disambiguate browser windows in `exwm`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something like this with ivy, but you might have to write some code to get exactly what you want. Here, I get the files in the current directory, and construct a list of candidates that looks like "filename | directory". If you want them on separate lines, replace | with \n. Then you use ivy-read to get completion. If you want a buffer where you can see the candidates, you type C-o U in the ivy-read minibuffer to open the candidates in an Occur buffer. The action function will be run on the entry you select.

```
(require 'f)
(require 'ivy)
(let* ((entries (f-entries "."))
       (directories (mapcar 'file-name-directory entries))
       (files (mapcar 'file-name-nondirectory entries))
       (candidates (mapcar* (lambda (f d e)
                  (cons (format "%s | %s" f d) e))
                files directories entries)))
  (ivy-read "f: " candidates
        :action (lambda (candidate)
              (message "you picked %s" (cdr candidate)))))
```

You can also do something like this with helm.